# Disable ValueChangeListener

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm new of vaadin and now I'm running in the following trouble. I have a TabSheet that contains a few tabs.[image]

Now my **Tax Code** component setted in immediate mode and others it has a the following ValueChangeLister

```
    TextField taxCode = new TextField();
    taxCode.setImmediate(true);
    taxCode.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

                if(taxCode.isModified()){
                    searchByTaxCode(taxCode.getValue());
                }               
            }
        });
```

then each time that the user changes the value to taxCode component, the method **searchByTaxCode** is invoked. This happens also when the user switch from Tab2 to Tab1 and I don't want this?

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what happens when you switch the tabs? do you save the values from the textfields and restore it again? if so, do it before adding the valuechange listener.

Comment: My target is just to avoid the ValueChangeListener when the user chenge the value of the taxCode and then switch in tab1

Comment: I wonder why the valuechangelistener is triggered by a tab change. Maybe you can post more of your code?

Comment: I'm wondering why are you using `taxCode.isModified()` this is useless, or maybe this is what causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple test app does not fire the ValueChangeEvent when switching tabs, only when actually changing the value in the TextField. You have something more that could influence the behaviour?

```
public class TabSheetEventsUI extends UI {

@WebServlet(value = "/tabsheetevents/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = TabSheetEventsUI.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    TabSheet tabSheet = new TabSheet();

    Panel tab1 = new Panel("Tab 1");
    Panel tab2 = new Panel("Tab 2");
    tabSheet.addTab(tab1);
    tabSheet.addTab(tab2);

    final TextField tab1tf = new TextField("tab1tf");
    tab1tf.setImmediate(true);
    tab1tf.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Value change event catched.");
        }
    });

    tab1.setContent(tab1tf);
    setContent(tabSheet);

}
```

}